Can not find where this shell script is breaking as it is looking for new folders to be created on a volume
I am trying to create a shell script that will run in the background on a mac that will open a google sheet url whenever a new folder is created on a specific volume just at the root level. It started breaking when I tried to add a function where it would wait for the folder to be named before opening the google sheet url. Any help or ideas please?
#!/bin/bash

# Directory to watch
WATCHED_DIR="/Volumes/KLP-Working"

# Google Sheets URL
GOOGLE_SHEET_URL="http://www.urlgoeshere.com"

# Function to open URL in Google Chrome
open_google_sheet() {
    osascript -e "tell application \"Google Chrome\" to open location \"$GOOGLE_SHEET_URL\""
}

# Function to check if the folder has been named
wait_for_naming() {
    parent_dir=$(dirname "$1")
    original_folder_name=$(basename "$1")

    while true; do
        # Look for the folder in the parent directory
        current_folder_path=$(find "$parent_dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "$original_folder_name" -o -name "*")

        if [ -d "$current_folder_path" ]; then
            current_folder_name=$(basename "$current_folder_path")

            # If the folder is no longer named "untitled folder"
            if [[ "$current_folder_name" != "untitled folder" && "$current_folder_name" != "Untitled Folder" ]]; then
                echo "Folder named: $current_folder_name"
                open_google_sheet
                break  # Exit the loop once the folder is properly named
            else
                echo "Waiting for folder to be named..."
            fi
        else
            echo "Folder no longer exists. Exiting..."
            break
        fi

        sleep 2  # Wait before checking again
    done
}

# Function to check if the watched directory exists
check_and_monitor() {
    while true; do
        if [ -d "$WATCHED_DIR" ]; then
            echo "Monitoring $WATCHED_DIR for new folders..."
            fswatch -0 --event Created "$WATCHED_DIR" | while read -d "" event
            do
                # Extract the created item's path relative to the watched directory
                relative_path="${event#"$WATCHED_DIR/"}"

                # Check if the path is at the root level (does not contain any '/')
                if [[ "$relative_path" != */* ]]; then
                    # Check if the created item is a directory
                    if [ -d "$event" ]; then
                        echo "New folder detected: $event"
                        wait_for_naming "$event"
                    fi
                fi
            done
        else
            echo "Waiting for $WATCHED_DIR to be available..."
            sleep 10
        fi
    done
}

# Start monitoring when the directory is available
check_and_monitor

Everything I have tried, I can not get it to update the folder name, so it keeps thinking the folder name is still "untitled folder"

are you using set -x to track what values are being used for your env-vars?

How about defining what you mean by breaking in your question?

It does not ever update the name of the folder so it continually thing the folder is called "untitled folder" even after the folder has been named
